# How to fix randomly dropping cookies (null) between Delphi and Java?

Tags: java, http, delphi, session-cookies

I am having a problem with null cookies being received on my Java back end when I can see they are not null and are being passed from my Delphi, Indy10, front end. This does not happen every time. Back to back calls can fail as can calls in a loop, but not all of them. They will be working just fine. Then the server will complain about multiple calls, saying they have a null cookie. Then after that, it will start working again. The cookie is the same cookie manager, it is not null before being sent, and it is not timed out.

```
//Delphi psuedo code for loop every 4 seconds since it is not unreasonable to have a call to the back end within 4 seconds of each other.

loop every 4 seconds
begin
  url := 'serverPath/someCall';
  ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create;
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;

  LogDebug := TIdLogDebug.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.Intercept := LogDebug;
  TIdLogDebug(IdHTTP.Intercept).Active := True;

  IdCompressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(IdHTTP);
  IdHTTP.Compressor := IdCompressor;
  IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
  IdHTTP.CookieManager := GetTheGlobalCookieManager;
  LogCookies(IdHTTP.CookieManager); //Edited
  try
  //PROBLEM HERE
    IdHTTP.Get(url, ResponseStream);  //The Cookie (sessionid) always looks VALID here.
                                      //But SOMETIMES the server says it is null and
                                      //throws an exception.
    S := ResponseStream.DataString;

  except
    PostTheException;
  end;

  //Do Stuff with S

  IdHTTP.Compressor.Free;
  IdHTTP.Compressor := nil;
  IdHTTP.Free;
  ResponseStream.Free;
end;
```

**New**

```
procedure LogCookies(CM: TIdCookieManager);
var
  Cookies: TIdCookieList;
  I: Integer;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
begin
  try
    Cookies := CM.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caRead);

    for I := 0 to Cookies.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Cookie := Cookies[I];
      OutputDebugString(PChar('Client Cookie: ' + Cookie.ClientCookie));
      OutputDebugString(PChar('Cookie Name: ' + Cookie.CookieName));
      OutputDebugString(PChar('Cookie Text: ' + Cookie.CookieText));
      OutputDebugString(PChar('Server Cookie: ' + Cookie.ServerCookie));
    end;
  finally
    CM.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caRead);
  end;
end;
```

LogCookies output:

```
[14900] Client Cookie: session=9E6A18164750844AB41C0FE76D0BE3BB
[14900] Cookie Name: session
[14900] Cookie Text: session=9E6A18164750844AB41C0FE76D0BE3BB; Path=/; Domain=127.0.0.1; Max-Age=899; Expires=Tue, 21-May-2019 14:10:25 GMT
[14900] Server Cookie: session=9E6A18164750844AB41C0FE76D0BE3BB; Path=/; Domain=127.0.0.1; Max-Age=899; Expires=Tue, 21-May-2019 14:10:25 GMT
```

Server side Java

```
    @GET
    @Path("someCall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response subscribeInstanceES(
            @CookieParam("session") String sessionId,
            @QueryParam("id") List<Integer> idList) {
        if (sessionId == null)             //The session is null right here
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid session: " + sessionId);
        ...More security checks
        ...Due the  work

//The original Cookie is gotten on login, this is a refresher   
       NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("session", sessionID, "/", "", "", 
900, false);
        return Response.status(200).cookie(cookie).entity("true").build();
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you validating the cookies on the client side? Just because Indy has a given cookie stored in the CookieManager does not guarantee it will be sent back to the server in any given request. It really depends on the content of the cookie's attributes and the URL that is being requested. You need to log those details so you can look for a pattern when the sessions are null. Chances are, they are null when cookies are not being sent back when expected. Log the raw requests actually being transmitted and check if they have proper `Cookie` headers or not

Comment: The server side Java code only reads, never sets the "session" cookie. Can you verify when and where the cookie actually is set (or maybe lost) on the Java side?

Comment: I edited the question. I added how the server gets and refreshes the cookie and also how I log the cookie on the Delphi side. The items I am logging are never empty. Are there other attributes I should be looking at and logging?

Comment: For more detailled logging I would assign a Indy Intercept component to the IdHTTP and then log all raw communication to a file until the exception happens, and check the actual HTTP request / response. (Other option: use the Fiddler2 HTTP proxy or WireShark to capture the communicaiton)

Comment: Exactly what mjn said. Log the client side cookies before AND after sending a request to make sure the cookie is being added/updated each time, and log the actual requests and responses to make sure the cookie is being passed back and forth each time. If you find a descrepency, show it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I added the Indy Intercept to the code above.  The output shows a Connect, Sent and Recv with cookie information, followed by two Disconnects. This goes on for a while with calls milliseconds apart. Then it will fail and just show two Disconnects. Is this because the back end is throwing an exception? It doesn't show Connected or Sent and Received.

Comment: @DarinBallweg I can't answer that without seeing the actual log. Are you using HTTP 1.0 or 1.1? Is there a `Connection: close` header in the response? When it fails, did `TIdHTTP` send the session cookie in the request?